# I don't seem to understand NoMethodError in Comments#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm sorry but I am fairly new to Rails and I can't seem to understand what the problem is. I am building an online forum and want my users to not only be able to edit their own post but also any comments that they may create. I keep getting a: undefined method `comment_path' for #<#:0x007fe5b6b0cbd0>. Any ideas?

routes:

```
PostitTemplate::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'posts#index'

  get '/register', to: 'users#new'
  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users, only: [:create, :edit, :update]

  resources :posts, except: [:destroy] do
    member do
      post 'vote'
    end
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :edit, :update] do
      member do
        post 'vote'
      end
    end
  end

  resources :categories, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

my comments edit.html.erb:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h2>Update Comment<small> - looks like you need some updating!</small></h2>
</div>

<h3><%= @post.description %></h3>

<%= render 'shared_partials/errors', errors_obj: @comment %>
<div class="well">
  <%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, :class=> "input", :placeholder=> "Comment goes here", :rows => "6" %>
    </br>
    <div class="button">
    <%= f.submit "Create a comment", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

comments_controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(params.require(:comment).permit(:body))
    @comment.post = @post
    @comment.creator = current_user

    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Your comment was created!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      render 'posts/show'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end

  def update
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    if @comment.update(comment_params)
      flash[:notice] = "You updated your comment!"
      redirect_to post_comments_path
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

rake routes:

```
           Prefix Verb  URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
             root GET   /                                           posts#index
         register GET   /register(.:format)                         users#new
            login GET   /login(.:format)                            sessions#new
                  POST  /login(.:format)                            sessions#create
           logout GET   /logout(.:format)                           sessions#destroy
            users POST  /users(.:format)                            users#create
        edit_user GET   /users/:id/edit(.:format)                   users#edit
             user PATCH /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                  PUT   /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
        vote_post POST  /posts/:id/vote(.:format)                   posts#vote
vote_post_comment POST  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/vote(.:format) comments#vote
    post_comments POST  /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
edit_post_comment GET   /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     post_comment PATCH /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  PUT   /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
            posts GET   /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                  POST  /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
         new_post GET   /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
        edit_post GET   /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
             post GET   /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                  PATCH /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                  PUT   /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
       categories POST  /categories(.:format)                       categories#create
     new_category GET   /categories/new(.:format)                   categories#new
```

Comment: what is the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: In which file and which line are you getting the error?

Comment: Under views/comments/edit.html.erb. Line 9 Raghu

Comment: right in the `<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your comments are nested resources, you'll need to pass the `@post` into your call to `form_for()`.

```
form_for [@post, @comment] do |f|
```

Comment: Wow man, thank you. I should have mentioned that before. I tried that as well so many times and never realized that my mistake was this `[@post @comment]` with no `,`. Thanks again!